# R language concatenating string with format output

Tags: r, format, paste

When I want "x1" where 1 is from a running counter but x is static
I tried to create a loop where:

iterator <- 1

> paste("x", format(iterator))

[1] "x 1"

Why does R add a space between the x and the 1?

How can I concatenate those two to make "x1"?

Comment: Use `paste0` or the `sep` argument i.e. `sep=""`

Comment: Thanks.  That was helpful.  Still learning this R language.

Comment: print(paste("x", 1, sep=""))